# removeObjectIdenticalTo issue on Iphone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm facing some strange behavior in my code. 
At first app launch i store an array firstLaunchBrands in NSUserDefaults to retrieve in other viewControllers.

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([sharedDefaults boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"])
{

    NSMutableArray *firstLaunchBrands =  [NSMutableArray new];

    NSMutableArray *purchasedBrands =  [NSMutableArray new];

    NSNumber* PaulMWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    NSNumber* PravanaWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    NSNumber* WellaWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    NSNumber* LorealWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    NSNumber* SchwarzWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
     NSNumber* zeroWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

    [firstLaunchBrands insertObject:PaulMWrapped atIndex:0];
    [firstLaunchBrands insertObject:PravanaWrapped atIndex:1];
    [firstLaunchBrands insertObject:WellaWrapped atIndex:2];
    [firstLaunchBrands insertObject:LorealWrapped atIndex:3];
    [firstLaunchBrands insertObject:SchwarzWrapped atIndex:4];
    [firstLaunchBrands insertObject:zeroWrapped atIndex:5];

[prefs setObject:firstLaunchBrands forKey:@"ActiveBrands"];


     [sharedDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
    [sharedDefaults synchronize];
    [prefs synchronize];

}
```

And i'm using UISwitchControl to enable/disable brands and store active brands in NSMuttableArray in SettingsViewController.

```
- (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([sender isOn]){

    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:0]){
        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"PaulM"];
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray insertObject:xWrapped atIndex:0];

    }

    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:1]){
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray insertObject:xWrapped atIndex:1];
        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"Pravana"];
    }

    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:2]){
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray insertObject:xWrapped atIndex:2];
        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"Wella"];
    }

    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:3]){
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray insertObject:xWrapped atIndex:3];
        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"Loreal"];
    }

    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:4]){
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray insertObject:xWrapped atIndex:4];
        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"Schwarz"];
    }

}
else
{

    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:0]){
        [prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"PaulM"];
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:xWrapped];

    }

    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:1]){
        [prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"Pravana"];
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:xWrapped];

    }
    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:2]){
        [prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"Wella"];
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:xWrapped];

    }
    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:3]){

        [prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"Loreal"];
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:xWrapped];

    }
    if(sender == [self.switchArray objectAtIndex:4]){

        [prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"Schwarz"];
        NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
        [self.ActiveBrandsArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:xWrapped];

    }
}
NSLog(@"array: %@", self.ActiveBrandsArray);
[prefs setObject:self.ActiveBrandsArray forKey:@"ActiveBrands"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

}

It works fine on iPhone 5/5s and 4s. But it does not work properly on Iphone 6/6S, Plus. 
When i try to disable any Switch Control at first time it does not remove object from array - self.ActiveBrandsArray. But switch goes disabled. And when i enable switch again the new object is inserted. And after i can remove objects, but those first object remain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some strange things here.

insertObjectAtIndex *inserts* an object. So if you already have six items stored in your preferences, and call insertObjectAtIndex with index 1 for example, the items that were previously at index 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, now move to index 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, so everything will get confused. Use setObjectAtIndex.

removeObjectIdenticalTo is tricky. It looks for an *identical* object. That is an object with the same object pointer. If you have two NSNumber with a value 2, they may or may not be the same object. But then you have the same problem as before, where removing say the object at index 2 will move other objects forward, from positions 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 to positions 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

You need to think hard what it is that you actually want to store in your preferences.

PS. Instead of [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] write @[0].

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured out finally! I've changed removeObjectIdenticalTo to removeObject and it works now on all devices. Strange but it worked well for iPhone 5 but not iPhone 6 and higher.